# what will happen when the number of data which is sampled through audio exceed the "bufferSizeInBytes" which is set in AudioRecord constructor?

Tags: android, audio, record, audiorecord

```
public AudioRecord (int audioSource, int sampleRateInHz, int channelConfig, int audioFormat, int bufferSizeInBytes)
```

This is  the Public Constructor  of `AudioRecord`, you can find the last parameter called `bufferSizeInBytes` , and it means "the total size (in bytes) of the buffer where audio data is written to during the recording." in android docs.

I  thought this is a  buffer for storing all data which is sampled from audio hardware. i have a question :

> If the number of  data which is sampled through audio exceed the
>   "bufferSizeInBytes" , what will happen, stop sampling or else?

I did some test , and found that nothing happened (it kept recording)even if the number of the sample data has exceeded. why?

> ```
> So  can anyone tell me what's the meaning about  "bufferSizeInBytes"
> ```

Answer (score 3):

It's the amount of audiodata which is buffered during recording.
It determines how often you have to pull the `AudioRecord` object via `read()`, and not the total amount which can get recorded during the `Audiorecord` object's lifetime.

If you don't read out of the `AudioRecord` object, recorded data is lost. It keeps recording, but audioframes which exceed the buffer-level are dropped.

If you read audio data from the object, the buffer fill-level is decreased.

Comment: can i see the audiodata buffer  as a queue , first in first out ; right?  if i read audio data out , will the corresponded data in audiodata buffer be deleted ?  thanks !