# Android AudioRecord buffer starts with a number of 0s before meaningful values

Tags: android, audio, audiorecord

I'm trying to record around 500 frames using AudioRecord, but it seems like AudioRecord's buffer initially gets partially filled with a number of 0s before capturing meaningful values.

I had to read the initial 10000 frames using an array in order to get to the actual values.

```
AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
        44100,
        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
        2*44100);
audioRecord.startRecording();
audioRecord.read(new short[10000], 0, 10000); // have to include this to remove redundant values
audioRecord.read(audio, 0, 500);
audioRecord.stop();
```

If I omit the third line, I'll end up with 500 zeros. This solution isn't neat and I need to know if I'm doing something wrong. Also, it's important to note that before the `read()` methods are called, the `state` is `STATE_INITIALIZED` and the `recordingState` is `RECORDSTATE_RECORDING`, also the `read()` methods return exactly the number of frames that they're supposed to read, so no problem there.

Comment: This is interesting... never verified the exact behavior myself. But it's possible the stream is just "fading in" due to some AGC on the mic. If you examine the first few thousand values... do they start out really small, then get bigger?

Comment: @greeble31 Yes, in fact they do. The problem is that I can't really think of any robust way to know where the actual "true" values begin.

Comment: I think you're dealing with a hardware limitation, here. I mean, it's not necessarily Android's fault. It's probably a feature your OEM decided to put on the mic. What is your use case? Do you have, say, a 2-second heads-up you're going to need to grab 500 samples?

Comment: @greeble31 Yes, I need 0.2 to 0.25 seconds

Comment: @greeble31 But I thought I was messing up with threads or something (startPlaying() does create a new thread, if I'm not mistaken?)

Comment: What do you mean, you need 0.2 to 0.25 seconds? What is startPlaying()?

Comment: @geeble31 Oops, I meant startRecording(). I need to record for about 0.22 secs (10000 frames) to start getting real values

Comment: Well, what I was getting at is, you could just record constantly. That way the mic is always "warmed up". You're constantly `read()`-ing out data. Then, when the time comes, you can say, "OK, starting with the _next_ read, I'm going to start saving data."

Comment: Reading from an `AudioRecord` does not create a new thread, but you may want to consider adding one yourself.

Comment: @greeble31 But do I have to `read()` when I don't need the data? If the buffer is filled, it will just override the previous data, right?

Comment: Yes, but the catch is, when you go back to it and do that `read()`, you're going to get the oldest data in the buffer. It'll be like 2 seconds old. I'll work up something as an answer.

Comment: @greeble31 I'm not quite sure how the audioRecord buffer works, but since the minBufferSize it's giving me is around 3500 bytes, I guess it'll be far less than 2 seconds old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `AudioRecord` correctly. The issue seems to be some AGC on the mic; as you observed, the values read out of the buffer gradually become larger over the first few ms. It is likely this is a hardware AGC, perhaps added by the manufacturer to inhibit a sharp "crack" at the start of each new recording.

As an aside: I have an old RAZR with AGC that's so aggressive, if you snap your fingers near the mic, it'll go silent for a full second, and then slowly fade in.

One solution to this problem is just to leave the `AudioRecord` recording on a long-term basis. Then, when you decide you need to grab your 500 frames, it'll already be "warmed up", and the values should be full-scale.

**EDIT**

I just unit-tested it, and it seems that `AudioRecord` does not overwrite the data in its internal buffer if you neglect to read it out quickly enough. Or, at least, it's not clear exactly what's happening with that data. So, a more complicated solution is necessary.

In this case, it looks like you'll have to ensure the buffer never overflows. That means calling `read()` at a fast enough rate. Depending on your architecture, you may find it easiest to dedicate a thread for this purpose.

If you simply use a 500 frame buffer in each of your reads, then when the time comes, you can just grab a copy of that buffer, which will be reasonably close to the "most recent possible" data streaming from the mic. This assumes you have been reading quickly enough such that your next read would block.

I say "reasonably close" because audio data is placed in the buffer in chunks of size `getMinBufferSize()/2`, if I remember correctly, and this is also the limit of `OnRecordPositionUpdateListener` resolution. So, you'll be somewhere close to the end, but it's hard to tell exactly how close.

Comment: @geeble31 Apparently if the buffer is filled, the new data is lost (does not overwrite the previous data). This is also mentioned in this answer: (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12002230/6307199)

Comment: Yes, you're right. It either doesn't overwrite the data, or something else funny is happening to that buffer. Revised my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Initial zeros in the buffer can be caused by buffering itself or resampling. See related posts:
 1. [Android AudioRecord Initialization delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590225/android-audiorecord-initialization-delay)
 2. [AudioRecord returns some empty data after start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45786636/audiorecord-returns-some-empty-data-after-start)